# ActiveMQ Bridge Configuration for Solace

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis, solace, solace-mq

I have a requirement to create a bridge between a Queue in ActiveMQ and a Queue in Solace. When ever there is a message in ActiveMQ Queue it should automatically get transferred to SolaceQ.

I'm struggling to find the steps for this configuration. I have ActiveMQ installed on my local machine. Request you to please throw some light on this.

FYI: I'm very new to ActiveMQ/Solace

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JustinBertram. I’m using 5.11.0 version and running on my local windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do this via JMS since both ActiveMQ and Solace support it. Check out ActiveMQ's docs here: https://activemq.apache.org/jms-to-jms-bridge

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mrc0113. I tried referring the above doc but not able to get the config details for Solace, like the jar files which need to be referenced etc. Request you to please let me know from where I can get those details from. TIA

Comment: ActiveMQ documentation isn't going to provide details about configuration for Solace's JMS client implementation. You should get those details from the Solace documentation.

Comment: @Shankar it looks like there is an example that someone did here: https://github.com/richard-lawrence/Solace-Camel-JMS-Bridge

And you can grab the latest Solace JMS jars from solace.com/downloads